# Why my date span element is not processed while loading jsp page for the first time? when I Clicked on Inspect element it is showing as below:

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, date, dojo

```
<td class="outputData"> 
<span name="pdDate" id="pdDate" placeholder="START DATE DD-MMM-YYYY" required="true" constraints="{datePattern : 'dd-MMM-yyyy',min:new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),max:new Date(modrfsDate)}" onchange="validatePrefDowntimes();" data-dojo-props="'readonly': 'readonly'" value="" type="text" dojotype="dijit.form.DateTextBox"> 
<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> 
</span> 
<span name="pdTime" id="pdTime" placeholder="START TIME HH:MM" constraints="{min:new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),timePattern:'HH:mm'}" onchange="validatePrefDowntimes();" data-dojo-props="'readonly': 'readonly'" required="true" value="" type="text" dojotype="dijit.form.TimeTextBox"> 
<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> 
</span> 
<span name="pdDateEnd" id="pdDateEnd" placeholder="END DATE DD-MMM-YYYY" required="true" constraints="{datePattern : 'dd-MMM-yyyy',min:new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),max:new Date(modrfsDate)}" onchange="validatePrefDowntimes();" data-dojo-props="'readonly': 'readonly'" value="" type="text" dojotype="dijit.form.DateTextBox"> 
<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span> 
<span name="pdTimeTo" id="pdTimeTo" placeholder="END TIME HH:MM" constraints="{min:new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),timePattern:'HH:mm'}" onchange="validatePrefDowntimes();" data-dojo-props="'readonly': 'readonly'" required="true" value="" type="text" dojotype="dijit.form.TimeTextBox"> 
<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> 
</span></td>
```

Instead It must be :::

```
<td class="outputData"> 
                <div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitLeft dijitTextBox dijitComboBox dijitDateTextBox dijitComboBoxOpenOnClick dijitTextBoxError dijitComboBoxError dijitDateTextBoxError dijitComboBoxOpenOnClickError dijitError" id="widget_pdDate" role="combobox" lang="en" widgetid="pdDate" style="border-color: rgb(217, 217, 217); border-width: 1px; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><div class="dijitReset dijitRight dijitButtonNode dijitArrowButton dijitDownArrowButton dijitArrowButtonContainer" data-dojo-attach-point="_buttonNode, _popupStateNode" role="presentation" popupactive="true"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitArrowButtonInner" value="▼ " type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation"></div><div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitValidationIcon dijitValidationInner" value="Χ " type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation"></div><div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" type="text" autocomplete="off" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" role="textbox" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0" id="pdDate" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true" aria-valuemin="Sun Apr 10 2016 13:56:32 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" aria-valuemax="Wed Apr 13 2016 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" aria-valuenow="Sat Apr 09 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" readonly="readonly" value="09-Apr-2016"><span class="dijitPlaceHolder dijitInputField" style="display: none;">START DATE DD-MMM-YYYY</span><input type="hidden" name="pdDate" value="2016-04-09"></div></div> 
                <div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitLeft dijitTextBox dijitComboBox dijitTimeTextBox dijitComboBoxOpenOnClick dijitTextBoxError dijitComboBoxError dijitTimeTextBoxError dijitComboBoxOpenOnClickError dijitError" id="widget_pdTime" role="combobox" lang="en" widgetid="pdTime" style="border-color: rgb(242, 27, 10); border-width: 2px; color: rgb(242, 27, 10);"><div class="dijitReset dijitRight dijitButtonNode dijitArrowButton dijitDownArrowButton dijitArrowButtonContainer" data-dojo-attach-point="_buttonNode, _popupStateNode" role="presentation"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitArrowButtonInner" value="▼ " type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation"></div><div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitValidationIcon dijitValidationInner" value="Χ " type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation"></div><div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" type="text" autocomplete="off" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" role="textbox" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0" id="pdTime" aria-valuemin="Sun Apr 10 2016 13:56:32 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true" aria-valuenow="Thu Jan 01 1970 13:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" readonly="readonly" value="13:00"><span class="dijitPlaceHolder dijitInputField" style="display: none;">START TIME HH:MM</span><input type="hidden" name="pdTime" value="T13:00:00"></div></div> 
                <div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitLeft dijitTextBox dijitComboBox dijitDateTextBox dijitComboBoxOpenOnClick" id="widget_pdDateEnd" role="combobox" lang="en" widgetid="pdDateEnd" style="border-color: rgb(217, 217, 217); border-width: 1px; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><div class="dijitReset dijitRight dijitButtonNode dijitArrowButton dijitDownArrowButton dijitArrowButtonContainer" data-dojo-attach-point="_buttonNode, _popupStateNode" role="presentation"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitArrowButtonInner" value="▼ " type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation"></div><div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitValidationIcon dijitValidationInner" value="Χ " type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation"></div><div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" type="text" autocomplete="off" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" role="textbox" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0" id="pdDateEnd" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" aria-valuemin="Sun Apr 10 2016 13:56:32 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" aria-valuemax="Wed Apr 13 2016 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" aria-valuenow="Tue Apr 12 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" readonly="readonly" value="12-Apr-2016"><span class="dijitPlaceHolder dijitInputField" style="display: none;">END DATE DD-MMM-YYYY</span><input type="hidden" name="pdDateEnd" value="2016-04-12"></div></div> 
                <div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitLeft dijitTextBox dijitComboBox dijitTimeTextBox dijitComboBoxOpenOnClick" id="widget_pdTimeTo" role="combobox" lang="en" widgetid="pdTimeTo" style="border-color: rgb(217, 217, 217); border-width: 1px; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><div class="dijitReset dijitRight dijitButtonNode dijitArrowButton dijitDownArrowButton dijitArrowButtonContainer" data-dojo-attach-point="_buttonNode, _popupStateNode" role="presentation"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitArrowButtonInner" value="▼ " type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation"></div><div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitValidationIcon dijitValidationInner" value="Χ " type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation"></div><div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" type="text" autocomplete="off" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" role="textbox" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0" id="pdTimeTo" aria-valuemin="Sun Apr 10 2016 13:56:32 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" aria-valuenow="Thu Jan 01 1970 13:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" readonly="readonly" value="13:00"><span class="dijitPlaceHolder dijitInputField" style="display: none;">END TIME HH:MM</span><input type="hidden" name="pdTimeTo" value="T13:00:00"></div></div></td>
```

Why the span is getting printed as it is ??

Comment: Please elaborate your requirement and share code where you are facing this issue

Comment: Please share your code, it's unclear what are your trying to achive right now.

Comment: Please post a minimum of your code (html, javascript, ...) and the result you are getting and what do you expect, and finally, one way to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've edited the question - the code was there (but a mess), just not formatted. @Priyanka - please check how to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Oh my dear lord, I'm nightmares looking at this code formatting...